# Getting null value for days calculated / added current date plus the user entered value

Tags: java, date, jsf, calendar, localdate

Getting null value for days calculated / added current date plus the user entered value

We are calculating a column value based on the user entered value ie 
Number of days entered by the User plus the current date.

```
private Date setdaysAttendanceApprovedWithAdditionalDays(int daysAttendanceApproved2) {

    Date currentDate = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(currentDate);

    c.add(Calendar.DATE, daysAttendanceApproved2);

    Date currentDatePlusUserInput = c.getTime();
    return currentDatePlusUserInput;
}
```

Desired Output

If a user enters the value of 10
then 
8 May 2020 Plus 10
the Output would be 18-May-2020
in the set NewDate

Issue

the setNewdate setdaysAttendanceApprovedWithAdditionalDays is the being set to null

```
<h:form>
<p:panel id="panel" header="New User">

    <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
        <p:outputLabel for="Additional Days" value="Additionaldays:" />
        <p:inputText id="additionaldays" value="#{saveMB.attendanceApprovalEntity.daysAttendanceApproved}">
        </p:inputText>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{saveMB.approveAttendance}" />
</p:panel>
</h:form>
```

saveMB.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "saveMB")
@ViewScoped
public class saveMB implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(saveMB.class);

private Integer daysAttendanceApproved;

public Integer getdaysAttendanceApproved() {
    return daysAttendanceApproved;
}

public void setdaysAttendanceApproved(Integer daysAttendanceApproved) {
    this.daysAttendanceApproved = daysAttendanceApproved;
}

private Date newdate;

public Date getNewdate() {
    return newdate;
}

public void setNewdate(Date newdate) {
    this.newdate = newdate;
}

private AttendanceFlow attendanceApprovalEntity;

public AttendanceFlow getattendanceApprovalEntity() {
    return attendanceApprovalEntity;
}

public void setattendanceApprovalEntity(AttendanceFlow attendanceApprovalEntity) {
    this.attendanceApprovalEntity = attendanceApprovalEntity;
}


@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    Map<String, String> params = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();

}

private Date setdaysAttendanceApprovedWithAdditionalDays(int daysAttendanceApproved2) {

    Date currentDate = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(currentDate);

    c.add(Calendar.DATE, daysAttendanceApproved2);

    Date currentDatePlusUserInput = c.getTime();
    return currentDatePlusUserInput;
}

public void approveAttendance(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    try {

        this.attendanceApprovalEntity.setNewdate(setdaysAttendanceApprovedWithAdditionalDays(this.attendanceApprovalEntity.getdaysAttendanceApproved())); 

    } catch (Exception e) {}

}
}
```

AttendanceFlow.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTENDANCE_FLOW")
@NamedQuery(name = "AttendanceFlow.findAll", query = "SELECT h FROM AttendanceFlow h")
public class AttendanceFlow implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ATTENDANCE_FLOW_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "ATTENDANCE_FLOW_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ATTENDANCE_FLOW_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "ATTENDANCE_FLOW_ID")
private Integer AttendanceFlowId;

@Column(name = "DAYS_ATTENDANCE_APPROVED")
private Integer daysAttendanceApproved;

@Column(name = "NEW_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date newdate;

public Date getNewdate() {
    return newdate;
}

public void setNewdate(Date newdate) {
    this.newdate = newdate;
}    

public Integer getAttendanceFlowId() {
    return AttendanceFlowId;
}

public void setAttendanceFlowId(Integer AttendanceFlowId) {
    this.AttendanceFlowId = AttendanceFlowId;
}

public Integer getdaysAttendanceApproved() {
    return daysAttendanceApproved;
}

public void setdaysAttendanceApproved(Integer daysAttendanceApproved) {
    this.daysAttendanceApproved = daysAttendanceApproved;
}

}
```

While Debugging I can find the value of

```
 this.attendanceApprovalEntity.getdaysAttendanceApproved
```

ie user entered value something like 10 , but I could not proceed afterthat

Comment: Does it work in a unittest?  Put this logic in a service and test... not jsf related

Comment: anveshijain: please do not use [java] tag as long as the problem is not demonstrable in a plain Java application class with `main()` method. Else you get completely unhelpful answers from ones who know nothing about JSF.

Answer (score 2):

## `LocalDate::plusDays`

Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) instead of outdated `Date` and `Calendar`. Check [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) for more details.

Do it as follows:

```
private LocalDate setDaysAttendanceApprovedWithAdditionalDays(int daysAttendanceApproved) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    return date.plusDays(daysAttendanceApproved);
}
```

**A quick demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(setDaysAttendanceApprovedWithAdditionalDays(10));
    }

    static LocalDate setDaysAttendanceApprovedWithAdditionalDays(int daysAttendanceApproved) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        return date.plusDays(daysAttendanceApproved);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-05-18
```

## *JPA* and *java.time*

Remove `@Temporal` annotation from the attribute. Also, note that if you are using [JPA 2.1](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr338/index.html) or earlier, you need to write a converter as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928424/localdate-between-using-jpa-2-1-criteria-api). If you are are using [JPA 2.2](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr338/index.html) or later, you do not need any converter.

Comment: So I tried your solution and in the Entity 

    @Column(name = "NEW_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date newdate;
    public Date getNewdate() {
        return newdate;
    }
    public void setNewdate(Date newdate) {
        this.newdate = newdate;
    }

I had to change from Date to LocalDate

Comment: I had to change from Date to LocalDate 

    @Column(name = "NEW_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private LocalDate newdate;
    
    public LocalDate getNewdate() {
        return newdate;
    }

    public void setNewdate(LocalDate localDate) {
        this.newdate = localDate;
    }

Comment: But i receive this error in the entity class

@Temporal should only be used on a java.util.Date or java.util. calender

Comment: @anveshijain - I've updated my answer to address this problem.

Comment: I understood some part of your solution , But I did not understand how to handle the LocalDate attribute for a DATE column.

Comment: @anveshijain - Just create a converter class shown in the link and it will be automatically applied to the attributes of type `LocalDate`. Remove `@Temporal` annotation from the attribute. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `GregorianCalendar` class instead. Today's date can be obtained with `date=new GregorianCalendar()` and the number entered by the user can be added with `date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,number)`.

Comment: `GregorianCalendar` in a *terrible* class, deeply flawed in design, as are the related `Calendar` & `Date` classes. These were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. See [Answer by Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61684496/642706) for a modern solution.

Comment: I have never had any problem using this "terrible" class however...